# POST JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, api, gmail

I am looking to create a PHP page that creates a google user account, The Oauth is working however I am now at a stage where I have to POST some data in JSON format to google to provision the account and I am totally at a loss I am afraid!

I have a PHP script that needs to post the information in the link below...

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert

Could anyone give me an example of what i should be doing to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Ok I tried the following without success, anyone any ideas as to what i am doing wrong? Is it because Google expects this in a JSON format?

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$managers_email =  $_POST['managers-email'];
$department =  $_POST['department'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$laptop = $_POST['laptop'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$quan = $_POST['quantity'];
$aastra = $_POST['phone'];
$sales = $_POST['sales'];
$salesteam =  $_POST['sales.team'];
$sales =  $_POST['support'];
$uid = strtolower($first_name.".".$surname);
$email = strtolower($first_name.".".$surname."@wandisco.com");
$full_name = $first_name." ".$surname;


//set up a connection variable for the page you will post data to
$curl_connection = curl_init$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];

'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users');

//curl basic setup
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;     Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//$_POST variables to pass
$post_items[] = 'primaryEmail='.$email;
$post_items[] = 'name='.$full_name;
$post_items[] = 'name.familyName='.$surname;
$post_items[] = 'name.givenName='.$first_name;
$post_items[] = 'password=9ceptuZQtg2H';;

//format the $post_items into a string
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//send the $_POST data to the new page
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
```

Comment: you can start here: http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: What is the resulting variable storing the Oauth form information?

Comment: random guess: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/curl)

Where a tutorial:
http://coderscult.com/how-to-post-data-with-curl-in-php/

--
Yes, you need convert to json first.